# Django - How to properly stream a matrix in a RESTful API?

Tags: json, django, rest

After computing some values from on the server side. The result is a matrix  (i.e a `pandas.DataFrame`) with the following format:

`0   1   2   3   4  5  6
0      1   0   0   0   2  0  6
100    0   0   0   0   0  0  0
200    0   0   0   0   0  0  0
300    0   0   0   0   0  0  0`

Where first row/column represents row/column indexes, and (just in this case) some of the values are zero.

What would be a popper JSON format to stream this matrix? Is there any standard way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest

```
{ 
  x_axis: [0,1,2,3],
  y_axis: [100,200,300],
  rows: [
         [1,2,3,4],
         [1,2,3,4],
         [1,2,3,4]
        ]
}
```

Comment: That can be achieved by using `pd.DataFrame.to_json(orient="split")`. Is this standard?